# Creating multilingual wordpress site with shared structure and php functions

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, multilingual

I know there are many multilingual wp plugins but I'm not sure which method should I use for this purpose;

I'd like to create a wp site with advanced features, partly coded by myself in php. Then I generally want to create duplicates of this site's **structure, design and behavior** in other languages, for example, es.blog.com would be a duplicate of en.blog.com. The content, however, shouldn't be shared.

I'd also like to keep **changing the code only at one place** and make those changes affect all the other languages duplicates, so I assume that means the code itself, or parts of it, would be shared.

Is there a way to have a shared structure, design and functions for several blogs, while the content of each blog is different?

Comment: I think you can use the soft links in linux to address the same code, and use the different wp-config.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a perfect case for WordPress Multisite.

> #### [Multilingual Network](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/multilingual-network) (forum thread)
>
> > *I would like for users to choose their language when they first get to the site - so they can choose to read, register, administer the entire site (front end and back) in either English, Kurdish (and perhaps others).*

> #### [How to set a bilingual or multilingual WordPress multisite blog](http://oncleben31.cc/en/how-to-bilingual-multilingual-wordpress-multisite-blog/) (blog post)
>
> > *I need two independent sites to facilitate the plugins and theme localization with an easy way to switch between languages if a translation is available. Another reason is to optimize the search engine indexing. With this solution I can have some language specific posts without translation.*

[ **update** ]

> #### [Multilingual Press](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multilingual-press/) (plugin)
>
> Each site/blog can then be attributed to a different language. Simply write a post or page in one language and Multilingual-Press will automatically create a duplication of it in the other sites/blogs. These new posts and pages are interlinked and are easily accessible via the post/page editor screen - you can switch back and forth to translate them! Multilingual-Press is WordPress conform, easy to install and doesn't make any changes to the WordPress core. It doesn't harm your website's performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any MVC framework to achieve this, and simply store the data in a database with a 'language' field and call only rows from that language.

Google 'MVC Framework'.

A good and free example would be CodeIgniter.

In CodeIgniter, you can include the Wordpress files in your 'libraries' folder then create a model with the specific functions you need to use.

Finally, you would have to create an .HTACCESS file to get the sub-domain section from the URL if you were to use this approach, however, again, there are many tutorials on achieving this, google 'htaccess URL rewrite'

Comment: What have this to do with wordpress?

Comment: You can put the Wordpress files into a CodeIgniter library and call them through CodeIgniter, then you can call any wordpress function by loading the library, thus not requiring you to edit multiple Wordpress files. Oh and downvoting because I downvoted you for encouraging bad practice... If OP used your approach, he is creating more work for himself. Using mine it's less and more efficient. That's why I downvoted. You just downvoted because I did.

Comment: I'm suggesting a more WP-vanilla approach. Yes, there are obvious downsides, but I leave it to the OP to decide.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't recommend WP for any true multilingual site, searches get messed up, plugin-incompability etc.

Install parallell WP-instances in subdirs and make one the "master" for dev/bugfixes. Content is isolated and you can use standard WP-features without metadata or plugin-hacks.

By "changing the code", I presume you mean the template? It's a simple drag'n'drop in a decent ftp-client.

Comment: Does your answer suggest creating a separate WP instance for each language or am I misreading this? This is completely unnecessary, never mind confusing. What if the person wanted to support 50 languages? Are you suggesting they 'drag and drop' the master file into 50 sub-directories when it's been fixed?

Comment: Yes. I have clients very satisfied with this setup, not 50 languages though, but efficient and simple. They wouldn't downvote.

Comment: Do your clients know your setup is inefficient and involves duplicating code when you can do it with one file? Or did you not tell them that? This is why I rarely come here: people giving bad answers and spitting their dummies out when told so.

Comment: @andrew, You should calm down or come here more rarely.